# Print statement in c

Tags: c, printf

`printf("%s Hello ", "%s Hello ");`

**output**:

`%s Hello  Hello`

Why is `%s` printed only for the first one and not for the second one?

Comment: This is a confusing example.  If you do `printf("%s Hello ", "Akanksha");`, does the result make sense?

Comment: In the first string you hand to `printf` (but only the first string), `%s` means, "plug in a string from a later argument".  That's what's happening here.

Comment: I think that you meant `printf("%s", "hello")`

Comment: Format string parsing is only done on the first argument; the other strings are literal. Also why you should not put the format string as a user argument.

Comment: `printf(a, b, c, ...);` does not mean "print a and b and c ...". It means "print a [replacing `%` specifiers with b, c, ...]"

Answer (score 4):

You see what is happening in your code carefully...

`printf("%s Hello","%s Hello");`

In this, the first `%s` acts like a variable which stores the String after comma i.e. `"%s Hello"`. This does not happen with the second one `%s` because that's after comma (second parameter of the function printf() ).

Like you do

```
printf("Number = %d",num);
```

where `%d` prints the value of `num` variable, in the same way

```
printf("%s Hello","%s Hello");
```

prints first the value of `%s` ("%s Hello") and then the String constant following it ("Hello")

That is why you see the output as

```
%s Hello Hello
```

Answer (score 3):

Printf takes N arguments, where the first one is a format string. It just so happens that "%s" means print the next argument as a string. Try this:

`printf(" Hello ", "World ");`

output: `Hello`

Based on [Serge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1143850/serge)'s recommendation, another good example:

`printf("- %s -", "Hello ");`

output:`- Hello  -`

Comment: the first half of this answer is almost as confusing as the original question!

Comment: @SteveSummit: I made a correction but I produced it I believe it's close to OP's original source of confusion.

Comment: I got it. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is `%s` printed only for the first one and not for the second one?

The `%s` printed is actually part of the second string, as can been verified with this example:

```
printf("%s Hello\n", "{%s Hello}");
```

which outputs: `{%s Hello} Hello`

The reason for this is the first argument to `printf` is a format string, where each `%` specifies a conversion for extra arguments. The `%s` in the first string expects a string argument that will be placed in the output unchanged, hence the second argument `"%s Hello"` will be output as is, and the rest of the format string follows, `Hello`, confusingly similar to the previous word.

`printf` has many conversion types and options, it is probably the most complex function in the C library. It takes some time to master, and it takes re-implementing it to fully understand all of its quirks and subtle issues.